# Servlet for download files from a specific folder?

Tags: java, servlets, upload, download

I am new to JAVA technology,especially Servlets.I need to make a Web application project which have an upload and a  download files to/from a server(tomcat).I have already an upload servlet,which works fine.

i have also a download servlet,found on the internet.But the problem is that this servlet allows downloading only a specific file,and the path to this specific file is given in the servlet. I need to let the client see the entire content of my upload folder and select which file he wants to download from this folder.

The code of the download servlet is this:

```
import java.io.DataInputStream; 
import java.io.File; 
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext; 
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;



 public class DownloadServlet extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet implements
            javax.servlet.Servlet {
        static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private static final int BUFSIZE = 4096;
        private String filePath;`

public void init() {
    // the file data.xls is under web application folder

    filePath = getServletContext().getRealPath("")  + File.separator;// + "data.xls";
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    File file = new File(filePath);
    int length   = 0;
    ServletOutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
    ServletContext context  = getServletConfig().getServletContext();
    String mimetype = context.getMimeType(filePath);

    // sets response content type
    if (mimetype == null) {
        mimetype = "application/octet-stream";
    }
    response.setContentType(mimetype);
    response.setContentLength((int)file.length());
    String fileName = (new File(filePath)).getName();

    // sets HTTP header
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");

    byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[BUFSIZE];
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));

    // reads the file's bytes and writes them to the response stream
    while ((in != null) && ((length = in.read(byteBuffer)) != -1))
    {
        outStream.write(byteBuffer,0,length);
    }

    in.close();
    outStream.close();
}
}
```

The JSP page is this:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
   pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Download Servlet Test</title>
</head>
<body>
Click on the link to download: <a href="DownloadServlet">Download Link</a>
</body>
</html>
```

I searched a lot of servlets but all of them were like this...they allowed downloading only a specific file.
Can anyone help me?
Thank you very much!

Comment: What have you tried? Have you made any modifications to the code you downloaded? What changes did you make? What worked? What didn't? Have you done any research beyond just looking for a complete solution you can download? Just copying and pasting code from the internet isn't going to get you very far, you'll have to do your own work sometimes.

Comment: @Adrian Thank you for your response.


As I said,the above code works fine for downloading only a file given as a path to it in Servlet.In this example,in the init() function.


I tried to give a path as a string for filePath attribute.example: filepath = "C://Apache//Application//data//",but i received an error:Access denied.


I tried something else: to make a list of contents of folder in my JSP with a file attribute and listFiles method,and then I write '<a href="<%=file.getAbsolutePath()%>" target="_blank"><br> <%=file.getName() %>' but that worked only in I.E. with save target as.

Comment: @user2236267 try using a different path, like *C:\\external\\path*. Also, make sure your user has enough permissions to write into that folder. I didn't included that info since I assumed you already knew it.

Comment: I am very new to JAVA programming.I tried a lot to manage how to resolve my problem but i did't find any solution.

I will try more,and if I will find any solution,i will post it here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you're handling the data on the `doGet` method, you can pass a parameter to the servlet where you indicate the name of the file you want to download. For this, you should assume that the file name exists in your base path. The code could go like this:

HTML

```html
<body>
    Click on the link to download:
    <a href="DownloadServlet?fileName=data.xls">Download Link</a>
</body>
```

Java Servlet Code:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    //retrieving the parameter by its name
    String fileName = request.getParameter("fileName"); //this will return `data.xls`
    //using the File(parent, child) constructor for File class
    File file = new File(filePath, fileName);
    //verify if the file exists
    if (file.exists()) {
        //move the code to download your file inside here...

    } else {
        //handle a response to do nothing
    }
}
```

Note that since the code now uses [`File(String parent, String child)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) constructor, your `filePath` should not contain the separator anymore (this will be handled by Java):

```
public void init() {
    // the file data.xls is under web application folder
    filePath = getServletContext().getRealPath("");
}
```

Comment: **Thank you very much for your answer**
I tried your code but I can not make it work.

Comment: @user2236267 give it a try. If it works for your needs, please mark the check below the reputation in order to mark the post as answer.

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow.it will take some time for me to work with this.

I tried to give a vote up to your answer but it told me that i need 15 reputation.I want to reply with my new code,but it tells that my comment is too big.

Comment: I don't understand how the client can see the entire content of my upload folder.There I have a lot of files..let's say test.txt,test.pdf,image.jpg.

And i want that the user select which of those files to download.Not only one,given as parameter in the html page.

Comment: to be more clear:client must see **different link for each file of my folder**.and then,he must click the link associated with that file that he wants to download.

Thanks!

Comment: @user2236267 that is a complete new requirement and it should be handled in a new question. Make sure to try something before posting a question. An idea to solve your requirement is to have a serlvet that will set a request attribute with a `List<String>` that contains the names of the files in the folder. To have a light on this, see [StackOverflow Servlet wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)

Comment: thank you very much for your help Luiggi Mendoza.

**Have a nice day!**

Comment: I think this approach is not safe. An experimented user (or hacker) might get a file from any folder in the system. What if the user send a request like:
`DownloadServlet?fileName=../../otherfolder/dbcredentials.xml`

Answer (score 2):

you can do like that

```
     public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res){
     res.setContentType("text/html);
      PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
      String fileName="home.txt";
      String filePath="d:\\";
    response.setContentType("APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;fileName=\""+fileName+"\"");
    int i;
    FileInputStream file=new FileInputStream(filePath +fileName);
    while((i=file.read()) !=-1){
      out.write(i);
   }
    file.close();
   out.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  // get MIME type of the file
    String mimeType = context.getMimeType(fullPath);
    if (mimeType == null) {
        // set to binary type if MIME mapping not found
        mimeType = "application/octet-stream";
    }
    System.out.println("MIME type: " + mimeType);

    // set content attributes for the response
    response.setContentType(mimeType);
    response.setContentLength((int) downloadFile.length());
```

This more detail and the question how to improve:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41914092/how-change-servlet-which-download-single-file-but-can-folderfew-files-in-fold