# Opening PDF file using window.open()

Tags: struts2, liferay

I've a method which generates a PDF file and stores it in `/temp` folder. I am using tomcat. I want to open the PDF file. I have tried this using `window.open()` method in the JavaScript. But on clicking the hyperlink it says the requested resource was not found.

I store the PDF file in `/temp` folder using following line (of course the file gets generated and saved in the location):

```
inputMap.put(TableProperties.PDF_PATH, "/temp/report.pdf");
```

Now in a JSP I try the following:

```jsp
<tr>
  <td>
    <a href="" onclick="javascipt:window.open('/temp
/report.pdf');" class="popup">Click to open.</a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

but its showing the following error:

```
The requested resource was not found. 

http://localhost:8080/temp/report.pdf
```

**EDIT:**

Tried the following:

in the JSP page, a download link to open the file:

```jsp
<tr>
  <td>
    <a href='<s:url action='gotoDownloadPdf'> </s:url>'>
      download
    </a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

**in `struts.xml`:**

```xml
<action name="gotoDownloadPdf" class="com.stp.portal.view.SearchServicePortlet" method="gotoDownloadPdf">
            <result name="success">/WEB-INF/view/pdfDownload.jsp</result>   
        </action>
```

a JSP page which contains the JavaScript to download the PDF file:

```jsp
<%@ page import="java.util.*,java.io.*"%>
<%@ page language="java"%>
<!--Assumes that file name is in the request objects query Parameter -->
<%
    //response.setHeader ("Cache-Control","no-cache");
    //response.setHeader ("Pragma","no-cache");
    //response.setHeader ("Expires",0);
    //read the file name.
    try
    {
        String fpath="/temp/"; 
        String fileName="report.pdf"; 
        fpath = fpath + fileName;  
        String fileType="pdf";

        File f = new File (fpath);
        
    
        //set the header and also the Name by which user will be prompted to save
        response.setHeader ("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\""+fileName+"\"");
        //get the file name
        String name = f.getName().substring(f.getName().lastIndexOf("/") + 1,f.getName().length());

        //OPen an input stream to the file and post the file contents thru the 
        //servlet output stream to the client m/c
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(f);
        ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();
        int bit = 256;
        int i = 0;
        try 
        {
            while ((bit) >= 0) 
            {
                bit = inputStream.read();
                servletOutputStream.write(bit);
            }
            //System.out.println("" +bit);


            }
            catch (Exception ioe) 
            {
                //ioe.printStackTrace(System.out);
            }
                    System.out.println( "\n" + i + " bytes sent.");
                    System.out.println( "\n" + f.length() + " bytes sent.");
            servletOutputStream.flush();
            //outs.close();
            inputStream.close();    
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
                
    }
                        
%>
```

Now when I click on the download link, nothing happens, it redirects to the JSP page, but the pop up window for download does not appear.

Comment: Please add an upper case letter at the start of sentences.  Also use a capital for the word I, and abbreviations and acronyms like JEE or WAR.  This makes it easier for people to understand and help.

Answer (score 1):

Think about what you're doing. Do you really think that typing `http://www.google.com/tmp/secretReport.pdf` in your browser address bar would give you access to some secret report left in the `/tmp` directory on the file system of the google server?

You can't access the file system of a server over HTTP like this. What you need is a servlet, invoked by the browser, that reads the PDF file and sends it in the HTTP response.

Comment: thnks. can you please give me some example on this. I have googled it a lot but not able to find out any working example.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15765799/servlet-for-download-files-from-a-specific-folder for example.

Comment: Don't use a JSP to send a file to the output stream. Use your Struts action directly.

Answer (score 0):

What you have wrong:

1. The file is created on server, thus it can't be opened on the client
   using JavaScript
2. The file needs to download first, you need to provide the url mapped to the action, probably with parameter which file you want to download. If you create a file in another action, you could show the name of the file in the JSP to download. Just use the action property for file name.
3. Java code in scriptlets is discouraged, use this code to implement the action used to return a `stream` result.

To your happiness there's an [example to download a file with struts2](https://www.codejava.net/frameworks/struts/sample-struts2-application-for-downloading-files). All you need is to apply it to your scenario.

Comment: thanks, I tried it, but its giving me the following error:
~application/octet-stream is not a supported mime type~

Is it because I am using liferay? Tried it for so many days but not able to solve it...

Comment: Nice to know that you are using liferay, because it's portlet related not struts2, if you not using portlet plugin then you should do, and try the portlet specific parameters in the result config. The mime time is valid but it is not a cause of the error.

Answer (score 0):

I see other's have already answered your result, but I see you are having difficulty in understanding their answer. Well, then I have something simpler to start from.

Simply create a folder named `/temp` in your Web Pages (site root) directory and then put a PDF (`report.pdf`) then that link will work.

Now all you have to do is simply put your report in that file using simple File IO.

For e.g. if you wrote code to write a PDF file named `xyz.pdf` in the `temp` directory (already available in your web-root) then the access url will be `/temp/xyz.pdf`.

Here's a small quick [example on how to download file using struts2](https://github.com/coding-idiot/Struts2-Examples/tree/master/Struts2FileDownload).

Comment: get the following error:
`application/octet-stream is not a supported mime type`

I am using Liferay. is the error because of this,

Comment: @user2670291: See my answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/17721094/1700321.

Comment: @Aleksandr: Thanks for your reply, seems like that user and we had the same issue. I tried using `portletUrlType="resource"` to the `<s:url>` tag. But the same error is coming. Below is the generated url after clicking the download link:
`http://localhost:8080/web/guest/print-month-end-report?p_p_id=searchserviceportlet_WAR_SSDG_DEMOportlet&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=column-2&p_p_col_count=1&_searchserviceportlet_WAR_SSDG_DEMOportlet_struts.portlet.action=%2Fview%2Fview%2Fdownload&_searchserviceportlet_WAR_SSDG_DEMOportlet_struts.portlet.mode=view`

Comment: @user2670291: This parameter `p_p_lifecycle=0` indicates that you haven't put `portletUrlType="resource"` to the url tag or that you haven't properly deployed your war.

Comment: I have wriiten the following in the jsp page:
`<a href='<s:url action='download' portletUrlType="resource"> </s:url>'>
      download
     </a>`
After that I have clean the project, I also cler the cache of the browser, but still the same result

Comment: @user2670291: If you try to change `p_p_lifecycle` from `0` to `2` and paste this url in your browser does it work?

Comment: @AleksandrM: I tried changing `p_p_lifecycle` from `0` to `2` but only a white screen appears and also no error message in the console

Comment: Which version of Struts2 and Liferay? Are you using `Jsr286Dispatcher`?

Comment: Struts 2.0 and Liferay 6.1. I am using Jsr168Dispatcher. Is it because of this? If so can you please tell me the procedure for migrating from Jsr168Dispatcher to Jsr268Dispatcher?

Comment: @user2670291: The jsr-168 doesn't support resource serving. Use jsr-286.