# How to forward after writing to an ourputstream

Tags: java, struts

I am working on a Java1.7 Struts1 application.

It can successfully download a file by doing the following:

```
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
        BufferedOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();
            fos = new BufferedOutputStream(output);
            fos.write(bytes);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Error trying to download the BAS file. "+e.getMessage());
        }
```

However, when when it does this, it changes the `HttpServletResponse` object. This means that when the Action class performs the following:

```
return mapping.findForward(forwards.success.toString());
```

It does not forward to that location (it just stays on the current page, i.e. does the download and nothing else).

If it does not do the download, i.e. does not change the `HttpServletResponse` object, then it does the forward successfully.

**Question**

How can I make it download the file (i.e. write to the `HttpServletResponse`, and then do the forward succesfully?

Comment: You can't do both. If you search for "http download file and redirect" (or similar) you'll find a number of possible workarounds. This is just the way HTTP works.

Comment: FYI: The server side is different than a client side. Theyalso use different programming languages. What you do in one is different in another. You should explore both for reasonable opportunity. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18165136/573032) answer must read.